# Chunk a file into variable sized read in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am attempting to read a file in different sized chunks to calculate the file etag and compare to etags on an s3 resource.

I realize this is a question that has been asked before, but all the answers I have seen involve even sized chunking that is consistent through processing.

What I am trying to do is take any sized file, and for the first 5GB of that file, calculate the md5 of each 5MB chunk. Then for the next 25GB of the file, calculate the md5 for each 25MB chunk. And for the final amount of the file, calculate the md5 for each 125MB chunk.

I believe this breaks down to:
1000 chunks of 5MB up to 5GB
next 1000 chunks of 25MB up to 25GB (or read to 30GB)
last 8000 chunks of 125MB each up to 1TB

S3 protocol limits the number of chunks to 10000 max.

So for a 49.9 GB file, I would end up with 2136 parts concatenated and md5 calculated.

Reasoning for this is the upload to the s3 appliance was done using Goofys which uploads based on this chunking scheme.

I've attempted using nested while loops (where my condition wasn't working as expected), and my present attempt is using if statements...

Where I am getting lost is making sure the file.read(chunk_size) changes as the size thresholds are reached until the entire file is read.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was making a poor assumption and the solution was easier than I thought. I was making it too difficult.

That stated, please feel free to give feedback to improve the code.

Here is my solution:

```py
import os, hashlib
from hashlib import md5

def etag_calc(inputfile):

    md5_digest = []
    partsize1 = 5*1024*1024
    partsize2 = 25*1024*1024
    partsize3 = 125*1024*1024

    with open(inputfile, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(partsize1), b''):
            md5_digest.append(hashlib.md5(chunk).digest())
            if len(md5_digest) < 1000:
                continue
            else:
                break

        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(partsize2), b''):
            md5_digest.append(hashlib.md5(chunk).digest())
            if len(md5_digest) < 2000:
                continue
            else:
                break

        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(partsize3), b''):
            md5_digest.append(hashlib.md5(chunk).digest())
            if len(md5_digest) < 10000:
                continue
            else:
                break

    return hashlib.md5(b''.join(md5_digest)).hexdigest() + '-' + str(len(md5_digest))
```

Comment: Thank you John. I realized that I posted it poorly today, I just hadn't had time to correct it.
There is also another issue with the code I had to correct in that the returned value for the < 5GB file should be returned simply as the md5 calculation while this code returns a double md5 calculation.
I will update the code as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

S3 actually stores parts with the headers created during upload, including ETag.  You can use the undocumented `x-amz-mp-parts-count` header from HeadObject then download each part with the other undocumented `partNumber` header during GetObject.  After downloading all the parts you can calculate the combined hash via `hashlib.md5(b''.join(md5_digest)).hexdigest() + '-' + str(len(md5_digest))`.  This technique will work regardless of which client created the object.  Reference:

https://github.com/gaul/undocumented-s3-apis#get-object-by-multipart-number

Comment: That is extremely helpful. Thank you very much